# PMD ruleset works on which standard

Tags: standards, pmd

I was going through the PMD documentation and found that it has 100s of rules against which it validate your code base.

Now my question is does PMD rule set follow or governed or inspired by any standards like CWE, SANS, OWASP, MISRA, CERT ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. All those standards are exclusively focused on software vulnerabilities. PMD has a much broader scope. It can detect design issues, error prone constructs, coding style issues, performance issues, etc.

There is no reason why items from those standards can't be built into PMD rules, but the scope of PMD is not limited to that.

For instance, there is [this PMD plugin](https://github.com/GDSSecurity/GDS-PMD-Security-Rules) which implementes a bunch of OWASP top 10 vulnerability checks.